# Convert own haarcascade xml to AS for marilena / flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, face-detection

my question is: How can I use my "own" haarcascade XML for marilena + flartoolkit? I have been googling like crazy and have stumbled upon this here:

http://www.moment77.se/flash-classes/code-snippets/convert-haar-cascades-from-xml-to-actionscript/

However the PHP script just doesn't work, the screen remains blank and I have also tried the servers of my friends.

What else can I do? Or is someone else able to execute it? Are there any other ways?

Comment: For one thing, the php won't work right because there are unescaped quotes inside of the output strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing two things.

1. Escape the quotes inside of first `echo`
2. Change the name of the node it was using to obtain `count` (at least for my sample data)

Final code looks like this

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('haarcascades.xml');
$stages = $xml->haarcascade_frontalface_alt->stages->_;

for($s = 0; $s < count($stages); $s++){
  $trees = $stages[$s]->trees->_;
  if($s == 0)
    echo "

    tree = firstTree = new FeatureTree(". $stages[$s]->stage_threshold.");";
  else
    echo "

    tree = tree.next = new FeatureTree(\". $stages[$s]->stage_threshold.\");";

  for($t = 0; $t < count($trees); $t++){
    $r1 = str_replace(" ", ",", trim(substr($trees[$t]->_->feature->rects->_[0], 0, strlen($trees[$t]->_->feature->rects->_[0])-1)));
    $r2 = str_replace(" ", ",", trim(substr($trees[$t]->_->feature->rects->_[1], 0, strlen($trees[$t]->_->feature->rects->_[1])-1)));
    $th = $trees[$t]->_->threshold;
    $lv = $trees[$t]->_->left_val;
    $rv = $trees[$t]->_->right_val;
    if($t == 0)
      echo "
      feature = tree.firstFeature = new Feature2Rects($th, $lv, $rv, [$r1], [$r2]);";
    else if($t == (count($trees) -1))
      echo "
      feature.next = new Feature2Rects($th, $lv, $rv, [$r1], [$r2]);";
    else
      echo "
      feature = feature.next = new Feature2Rects($th, $lv, $rv, [$r1], [$r2]);";
  }
}
```

Notice the `$xml->haarcascade_frontalface_alt` usage when creating the count?  That was changed because the xml I am using looks like this at the top

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
    <haarcascade_frontalface_alt type_id="opencv-haar-classifier">
        <size>20 20</size>
        <stages>
```

You will want to change that name to whatever your top-level node is named.

The output looks like this (but much longer)

```
feature = tree.firstFeature = new Feature2Rects(-0.0951507985591888, 0.6470757126808167, 0.4017286896705627, [5,3,10,9,-1], [5,6,10,3,3]);
feature = feature.next = new Feature2Rects(6.2702340073883533e-003, 0.3999822139739990, 0.5746449232101440, [15,2,4,10,-1], [15,2,2,10,2]);
```

Comment: Dude, it works thank you VERY much for your fast and detailed answer for a beginner like me!!! Especially the second point was something it would take a long time for me to figure it out, thanks again!